# Dúvida sobre banco de dados

Tags: banco-de-dados

Alguém sabe me dizer para que serve as aspas duplas no nome tabela em uma consulta?
exemplo:
select * from "aluno" where nome= 'stefany'

o que as aspas duas da tabela aluno faz de diferente?

Comment: Depende da engine de banco de dados. Mas no geral aspas duplas delimitam identificadores de objetos do banco de dados e aspas simples delimitam strings e/ou datas.

Answer (score 1):

As aspas duplas são delimitadores ANSI padrão para identificadores, quando você executar a instrução `select * from "aluno"`, vai retornar os mesmos dados de uma instrução `select * from aluno`.

As aspa duplas também significa que um determinado valor é do tipo char

Answer (score -1):

No ANSI SQL, duplas aspas são usadas em nomes de objetos (como por exemplo, tabelas) elas permitem que eles contenham caracteres não permitidos de outra forma ou sejam iguais às palavras reservadas.